# What is the default ORDER BY if I use SELECT statement in mysqli::query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

If I have a table like this:

```
int        VARCHAR        int
----------------------------------      
 1          "U"            1
 2          "A"            1
 3          "B"            1
```

and I run a query through php's mysqli like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM " . parent::GetTableName();
if ($current_user_only == TRUE)
    $sql = $sql . " WHERE userID_FK=" . parent::GetUserID();

$result = $this->get_db_con()->query($sql);
if ($result == FALSE)
    throw new Exception("SQL exec failed (". __FILE__ . __LINE__ . "):      $this->get_db_con()->error");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo($row[1]);
}
```

I get an output like this:

```
 2          "A"            1
 3          "B"            1
 1          "U"            1
```

That is the result seems to be sorted by the VARCHAR column. If I run the same query in SEQUEL PRO it gives me results in the order I'm expecting which is the order in which they are entered in the table.

Any ideas?

Comment: you should explicitly set the *order by* no mater the db.

Comment: ALTER TABLE `table` ORDER BY `id`

Comment: If I actually don't care about the order should I still "ORDER BY"? Would it would impact performance?

Comment: @Manish: yes, it will impact as you're still forcing the DBMS to sort the result set. On a large result, that can force using an on-disk file to buffer the results, which can kill performance. If you don't need sorted results, then don't demand a sort be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: there is none.

Long answer: 
For MyISAM tables it's the natural order, i.e. the order in which rows are stored on disk, which is usually the order of insertion. This can be modified by running `ALTER TABLE ORDER BY`
For InnoDB tables it's the order of primary key.

Comment: I'm using InnoDB tables, my results are not being sorted by PK.

Comment: A bit of oversimplification on my side. InnoDB's PK is a base for clustered index, in which all data is stored. It is a tree-like data structure. Rows are returned in order in which this structure is traversed.

Answer (score 4):

I would never assume any specific order without an order by clause. If you want to have the rows sorted by ID, than use an `order by ID`.

Comment: Does it impact performance? I would not want to "order by" if it does.

Comment: If it has to sort, it will of course have an impact on performance. But it will be faster than sorting yourself, especially in PHP. If you don't care about the order, then don't use order by. If you do, then use order by. Databases are very fast. Don't optimize if you don't have to.